# What is the "correct" or best way in jax to implement a Dense layer where each layer might or might not have a bias?

Tags: jax

For example in `jax.experimental.stax` there is an Dense layer implemented like this:

```py
def Dense(out_dim, W_init=glorot_normal(), b_init=normal()):
  """Layer constructor function for a dense (fully-connected) layer."""
  def init_fun(rng, input_shape):
    output_shape = input_shape[:-1] + (out_dim,)
    k1, k2 = random.split(rng)
    W, b = W_init(k1, (input_shape[-1], out_dim)), b_init(k2, (out_dim,))
    return output_shape, (W, b)
  def apply_fun(params, inputs, **kwargs):
    W, b = params
    return jnp.dot(inputs, W) + b
  return init_fun, apply_fun
```

If we implement bias as being allowed to be None for example, or params having length 1, there are implications for how grad works.

What is the pattern that one should aim for here? `jax.jit` has a `static_argnums` that I suppose could be used with some `has_bias` param but book-keeping this is involved and I am sure there must be some examples *somewhere*.

Comment: Maybe flax is a good place to find examples.

Comment: It seems flax does this by taking the tensorflow/keras approach and slipping function options into the class state.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Haiku](https://dm-haiku.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)? You could do e.g. `hk.Linear(n, with_bias=False)`

Comment: @Kris Yes I will likely use that going forward just trying to stay light at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work ?

```py
def Dense(out_dim, W_init=glorot_normal(), b_init=normal()):
  """Layer constructor function for a dense (fully-connected) layer."""

  def init_fun(rng, input_shape):
    output_shape = input_shape[:-1] + (out_dim,)
    k1, k2 = random.split(rng)
    W = W_init(k1, (input_shape[-1], out_dim))
    if b_init:
        b = b_init(k2, (out_dim,)
        return output_shape, (W, b)
    return output_shape, W

  def apply_fun(params, inputs, **kwargs):
    if len(params) == 1:
        W = params
        return jnp.dot(inputs, W)
    else:
        W, b = params
        return jnp.dot(inputs, W) + b

  return init_fun, apply_fun
```